# Is ok to use undocumented SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I was hooking NtQuerySystemInformation for educational purposes and I came into one working structure for SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION. Then some questions raised on my mind:

1 - Is OK to use this structure?

2 - What is the official structure?

3 - How people discovered this undocumented structure?

Here is part of the code I'm talking about, containing the structure:

```
//here is what i'm talking about
type
PProcessInfo = ^TProcessInfo;
TProcessInfo=record
dwOffset : dword;
dwThreadCount : dword;
dwUnkown1 : array[0..5] of dword;
ftCreationTime : TFileTime;
dwUnkown2 : dword;
dwUnkown3 : dword;
dwUnkown4 : dword;
dwUnkown5 : dword;
dwUnkown6 : dword;
pszProcessName : PWideChar;
dwBasePriority : dword;
dwProcessID : dword;
dwParentProcessID : dword;
dwHandleCount : dword;
dwUnkown7 : dword;
dwUnkown8 : dword;
dwVirtualBytesPeak : dword;
dwVirtualBytes : dword;
dwPageFaults : dword;
dwWorkingSetPeak : dword;
dwWorkingSet : dword;
dwUnkown9 : dword;
dwPagedPool : dword;
dwUnkown10 : dword;
dwNonPagedPool : dword;
dwPageFileBytesPeak : dword;
dwPageFileBytes : dword;
dwPrivateBytes : dword;
dwUnkown11 : dword;
dwUnkown12 : dword;
dwUnkown13 : dword;
dwUnkown14 : dword;
ThreadInfo : PThreadInfo;
end;
//finish here, below is just some little snippet of the code

function NtQuerySystemInformationCallbackProc(dt : dword; buf : pointer; bufsize : dword; retlen : pointer) : dword; stdcall;
type
PBA = ^TBA;
TBA = array[0..1000000] of byte;
var
tmpbuf: PBA;
ProcessInfo ,LastPinfo : PProcessInfo;
cp: DWORD;
curproc:string;
begin
Result := NtQuerySystemInformationNextHook(dt,buf,bufsize,retlen);
if dt<>5 then exit;
if result<>0 then exit;
cp := 0;
tmpbuf := buf;
continues....
```

There are few more undocumented structures for this, but this one is the only I could make work properly.

Comment: 1 - If is undocumented, then is unsupported. 2- Official structs -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, 3 - Reverse enginering, disassembling, retrieving from symbols.

Comment: Also see [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: If you want to use this, use the declarations in JwaNative unit from the Jedi ApiLib project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is OK to use this structure?

That is up to you. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724509.aspx) says:

> NtQuerySystemInformation may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows. Applications should use the alternate functions listed in this topic.

I suppose the decision comes down to whether or not you care if your application works in case the structure is changed, the function is removed or has its behaviour modified.

> What is the official structure?

That can be found at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724509.aspx).

> How people discovered this undocumented structure?

The structure is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724509.aspx). The interpretation of the reserved fields is most likely to have been discovered through reverse engineering. Another possibility is that the information leaked, either from a Microsoft staffer, or from somebody reading the source code under NDA.

Comment: Yes but in MSDN there's no reference about that TProcessInfo struct in the code. That's what Im talking about.

Comment: With the official and documented structure is possible to work the same way I'm doing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment

Comment: `TProcessInfo` is a Delphi representation of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION`, but with some extra guesswork regarding the reserved fields.